# Coding questionn

Tags: python

having trouble with the question that goes like this: "Write a function is_capital(state, city) that returns True if the named city is the capital of the named state, and False otherwise. Every city and state in the following table should be recognised." Where I'm given a dictionary with key-value pairs. I've tried answering this and what I have so far is;

```
def is_capital(key, value):
    if key and value in CAPITALS:
        print("True")
    else :
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for utilising a dictionary's built-in *get()* function which will return None if the given key cannot be found. Therefore:

```
CAPITALS = { 'Victoria': 'Melbourne', 'New South Wales': 'Sydney', 'Queensland': 'Brisbane'}

def is_capital(key, value):
  return CAPITALS.get(key) == value
```

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten about the .get method, will try a variation using it!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```py
if key in CAPITALS and CAPITALS[key] == value:
    ...
```

Comment: I see, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for your help :))

Answer (score -1):

In line with C137, but adding the `value` parameter check:

```
CAPITALS = { 'Victoria': 'Melbourne', 'New South Wales': 'Sydney', 'Queensland': 'Brisbane'}

def is_capital(key, value):
    if (key in CAPITALS) and (value in CAPITALS.values()) and (CAPITALS[key] == value):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Testing:

```
is_capital("California", "Los Angeles")        # False
is_capital("New South Wales", "Los Angeles")   # False
is_capital("New South Wales", "Brisbane")      # False
is_capital("New South Wales", "Sydney")        # True
is_capital("Victoria", "Melbourne")            # True
```

Also take into account that you are said to `return` the bool value, not to `print` it

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex. See my answer for a robust and simpler approach